# how i get key child values from firebase database into angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access data from comments node, please help to solve.

Database structure

[image: Database structure]

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,public af:AngularFireAuth,private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){ 
        this.activatedRoute.params.forEach(param => {
            var node =(param['node']);
            var key=(param['key']);
            this.items = db.list('/Comments',{
                query:{
                orderByChild: 'text'
            }
            });

       });
    }
```

this is html code

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <div class="card">
     <h5>{{item.text}}</h5>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how i access comments all  text fields.plz help to solve.

Comment: Why your database has 2 nested keys in comments?

Comment: There's a difference in spelling of comments in the code and data: ` db.list('/Comments'` vs `/comments`.

Comment: @FabioCampinho 1 key login user id and 2nd all fields key.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i change spelling but it gives only all user keys.it not give text output.

Comment: User key must go inside all field keys with value true

Comment: @FabioCampinho sori for late reply... how to get firebase database nested data access inside

Comment: hello @FabioCampinho ,FrankvanPuffelen  i solved issue,i used two for loop access comment text.thank you for response.